# Is there a way to to display reply form on same page and not in a new tab/window when using Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm()

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am using the office js method for a task pane read add-in in order to insert text into a reply

[`Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-1.7#outlook-office-messageread-displayreplyallform-member(1))

However on the web client it opens up in a new tab which is not ideal as its a bit of a disruptive experience. In the docs it says:

> In Outlook on the web, the reply form is displayed as a pop-out form in the 3-column view and a pop-up form in the 2-column or 1-column view.

Is there a way to stop it opening as a "pop-out" so to speak?

I have come across a setting for Dialogues called [Office.DialogOptions.DisplayInIframe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialogoptions?view=common-js-preview#office-office-dialogoptions-displayiniframe-member) but it seems that is for dialogs which looks like a separate component, wondering if it can be used or if there is something similar for the reply form?

Would be great if anyone can shed some light on the above

Comment: This is by design, and not possible as of today. You may submit a request for the same. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Answer (score 1):

No, the JavaScript Office API (`OfficeJS`) library doesn't provide anything for that.

> I have come across a setting for Dialogues called Office.DialogOptions.DisplayInIframe but it seems that is for dialogs which looks like a separate component, wondering if it can be used or if there is something similar for the reply form?

You are on the right avenue - that is for dialogs.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.